# How did my "Boot Device Not Found" error resolve itself?

Tags: windows-7, boot, ssd, hardware-failure

This morning, I turned on my computer and got the "Boot Device Not Found" error. I restarted the PC a couple of times, but the error persisted. I finally restarted the computer and booted off of the Windows 7 DVD, but it seemed to not find the existing OS installation. After that, I restarted once again, and the PC booted normally. Is my SSD failing (note: my primary HD is my SSD)? Is there a way to check if it is? Could this just be a weird "glitch" that does not indicate an underlying problem?

I did not install any new updates or software for several days now.

My "limited" specs:

- Mobo: ASUS P8Z77-V Pro
- HD: crucial 256GB m4 SSD
- OS: Windows 7 SP1
  64-bit

Please let me know if you need more info.

Output from crystaldiskinfo:

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, answering this question is going to be too hard as it can be a lot of things. It is possible that your SSD is dying and that it didn't detect it, and as such, gave this error. Had it myself too with an SSD that finally decided to give up and never worked again anymore. But to be sure? I can't.

Comment: PSU-glitch? Which voltages are required for the SSD<->MB communication?